# Add multiple tags to table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-functions

I have a table `tags` in database and I want create a query that was based on add values if not exist `name` of tag, next selected ID and if name exist selected tag ID

I creat a simply code:

```
DELIMITER $$
USE `cc`$$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS getTagId$$
CREATE FUNCTION getTagId (tag CHAR(20)) RETURNS  INT CHARSET utf-8
    BEGIN
       DECLARE id INT
       set @id = (select id from tags where name = @tag)
           if (@id is null) then
            insert into tags(name) values(@tag)
            set @id = (select last_insert_id())
           end if
        SELECT @id
    END
delimiter;
```

But this code doesn't work (This is my first function in MySQL).

I want add to database more tags then 10 in single query, do you have any ideas on how to optimize?

Comment: In which way it doesn't work?

Comment: Well, it is a very simple operation, so it is efficient. Functions are not efficient, in MySQL (unless they save a lot of network traffic, but this is not the case).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But probably my old answer is useless. The real question is: is this Stored Function really needed? I guess you are trying to do this just to avoid duplicates.

To reach the same goal:

- add a UNIQUE index to tags.name
- use INSERT IGNORE (no error if that tag already exists)

Comment: Federico, is it more efficient? I need it for add 600 tags per minute.

Comment: Jakub, 10 1-field INSERTs in a second can't really be a problem. Also, consider than: Stored Procs are slow in MySQL; and an explicit SELECT is always slower than enforcing a UNIQUE constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `$$` before last line.

And also, you forgot a lot of `;`

Returning a number and specifying the charset is absurd, and probably is a syntax error.

Drop all lines with `@id` and simply add `RETURN last_insert_id();`

IF NOT EXISTS ((select id from tags where name = tag)) THEN

(also note that I removed @ from tag!)

Probably there are more errors, but star with these :)